# How to merge the 3rd column to multiple columns

Tags: linux, awk, sed

How to merge the 3rd column to x, which starts off looking like this.

```
16 JUN  TRANSFER                                          blank          150       
        FROM ABC SOME COMPANY PTY LTD
18 JUN    VISA DEBIT PURCHASE CARD 1184                   14                blank    
          7-ELEVEN SYDNEY                                                      
          EFFECTIVE DATE 16 JUN 2020                                                                                                                                        
19 JUN    VISA DEBIT PURCHASE CARD 1184                 19.75               blank    
          DAISO SYDNEY                                                             
          DATE 17 JUN 2020
```

and ends up in one line separating the DATE, DETAILS, FEE, FEE

```
16 JUN, TRANSFER FROM ABC SOME COMPANY PTY LTD, BLANK, 150
18 JUN, VISA DEBIT PURCHASE CARD 1184, 7-ELEVEN SYDNEY, DATE 16 JUN 2020,14, blank
19 JUN, VISA DEBIT PURCHASE CARD 1184,DAISO SYDNEY, DATE 17 JUN 2020, 19.75, blank
```

Comment: Please do share your tried code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: I dont have any good examples, of how to do it, looking for possible solution.

Comment: My take would be to use arrays of AWK. You have a number of transactions. All comments (additional data) like "7-eleven" etc is probably indented. So if you meet a line that's NOT indented, it's a new transaction (increase TAcounter). If not, add line as comments to current transaction index in array. At the end, process arrays.   Hope this helps you to try something.

Comment: What is the source of this input? Are you copying this from excel sheet or some other source and pasting it here?  I would like to understand the invisible special characters present in your input. Could you paste your input after copying it from source in vim editor and run `:set list` and then copy it and add it here?

Comment: I can't post the full source because this is my bank records, I'm using it to do my task.

Comment: What do you mean by "3rd column"?  In the line " EFFECTIVE DATE 16 JUN 2020", the 3rd column is the string "16".  Probably your first challenge is to provide a rigorous definition of "column" that matches your intuition.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/ {2,}|$/, /g
        /(,.*), (.*,.*, )\n(,.*)/{s//\1\3\2/;$!ba};s/, (\n|$)/\1/;P;D' file
```

Replace two or more spaces or the end of a line, by `,` , that is form columns.

Append the next line and if it begins with a comma, prepend it to the 3rd column and repeat.

Otherwise, remove the introduced `,`  at the end of the first line in the pattern space, print/delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: I'm on linux, I tried that but got error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 0):

There is a great page: [The Grymoire - AWK](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

If the data are in the `data.txt` file, give a try to this:

```
awk '
/^[0-9][0-9]*[[:blank:]]/ && NF > 3 {
  if (last_cols) {
    printf(", %s\n",last_cols);
  }
  printf("%s %s, ",$1, $2);
  last_cols=$(NF-1) " " $NR;
  for(i=3; i< NF-1; i++) {
    if (i>3) { 
      printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%s",$i);
  }
  next;
}
{ 
  if (NF>=1) {
    printf(", ");
  }
  for(i=1; i<= NF; i++) {
    printf(" %s",$i);
  }
}
END {
  printf(", %s\n",last_cols);
}' data.txt
```

generated output:

```
16 JUN,  TRANSFER,  FROM ABC SOME COMPANY PTY LTD, blank 16
18 JUN,  VISA DEBIT PURCHASE CARD 1184,  7-ELEVEN SYDNEY,  EFFECTIVE DATE 16 JUN 2020, 14 VISA
19 JUN,  VISA DEBIT PURCHASE CARD 1184,  DAISO SYDNEY,  DATE 17 JUN 2020, 19.75 CARD
```